# Customize xfce suspend command

Tags: xfce, power-management, suspend

Is there a way to change the command executed by `xfce4-power-manager` when it wants to suspend? I assume it runs `xfce4-session-logout --suspend`, but I would like it to run

`xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/presentation-mode -s false 
&& xfce4-session-logout --suspend`

instead. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You must tell more about your system ! What dm do you use ? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by placing a script in the following location: `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`. The script contained the following:

```
#!/bin/sh  
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/usr/user/UID/bus su USER -c "xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/presentation-mode -s false"
```

UID should be replaced by the relevant user id (`$ id -u`), and USER by the name of the user the script is for (`$ whoami`).

I tested [jbrock's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526101/209149), and that also seemed to work, although I find the systemd option slightly cleaner since it doesn't redirect any command references.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works Simon. Add this script to your `~/bin` folder and name it `xfce4-session-logout`. Please follow up if you would like assistance in setting up a `~/bin` folder, i.e. making sure it is in your `$PATH` or making the script executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "--suspend" ]; then
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/presentation-mode -s false && /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout --suspend
else
    /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout "$@"
fi
```

Comment: That looks like a good idea! I'm currently tinkering with `systemd/system-sleep/` scripts. I'll try both and let you know whether it works!

Comment: @Simon The systemd sleep commands did actually occur to me after posting my answer. I've used that before for a bug workaround. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866162 (workaround at bottom). I am pretty sure you'll need to include those `export` commands for the `xfconf-query` command to work for the systemd sleep option.

Comment: I got it to work using systemd, but your solution worked as well. I posted my method as a seperate answer as well.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad to hear both worked. I agree as well that the systemd option is cleaner.